# How do I place the select button to the right of the show schedule expansion panel?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-btn class="success">Select</v-btn>
    <v-expansion-panels>
      <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-header>Show Schedule</v-expansion-panel-header>
        <v-expansion-panel-content>
          <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Monday</td>
                  <td>10.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Tuesday</td>
                  <td>20.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Wednesday</td>
                  <td>15.00</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </template>
          </v-simple-table>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

My codepen like this : https://codepen.io/happyforever/pen/pooBYgV?editors=1010

so when it opens in the mobile version, it doesn't take up much space

How can I do it?

**Update** :

I want it seems like this : https://codepen.io/happyforever/pen/gOOJbpe?editors=1010

But if user click show schedule, I want cols of  changes from cols = 8 to cols = 12

Check it in mobile version

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I had update my question

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 whether my question is clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the cols from 8 to 12 in mobile version. But you need to **use v-flex** to achieve the same **instead of v-cols**

> Here is the working codepen:
>   https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/jOOozoe?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row>
       <v-flex md8 xs12>
          <v-expansion-panels>
            <v-expansion-panel>
              <v-expansion-panel-header>Show Schedule</v-expansion-panel-header>
              <v-expansion-panel-content>
                <v-simple-table>
                  <template v-slot:default>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Monday</td>
                        <td>10.00</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Tuesday</td>
                        <td>20.00</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Wednesday</td>
                        <td>15.00</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </template>
                </v-simple-table>
              </v-expansion-panel-content>
            </v-expansion-panel>
          </v-expansion-panels>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex md4 xs6>
            <v-btn class="success">Select</v-btn>
         </v-flex>
     </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

})
```